# SilverStripe 3.0 ModelAdmin Filter results not editable

Tags: silverstripe

Hey All I have a class Shared Data that extends ModelAdmin

```
class SharedData extends ModelAdmin
{
// Managed models - Each model automatically get a tab added to Shared Data admin page
public static $managed_models = array(
    'Unit' => array('title' => 'Units'),
    'UnitType' => array('title' => 'Unit Types'),
    'StudentType' => array('title' => 'Student Types'),
    'EmpArea' => array('title' => 'Employment Areas'),        
);

public static $model_importers = array(
    'Unit' => 'UnitCsvBulkLoader',
    'UnitType' => 'CsvBulkLoader',
    'StudentType' => 'CsvBulkLoader',
    'EmpArea' => 'CsvBulkLoader',        
);

public static $url_segment = 'shared-data';

public static $menu_title = 'Shared Data';

// Place it right below the Pages menu item which has a priority of 10
public static $menu_priority = 9;
}
```

And I have a models for all of the $managed_models. For example the model for EmpArea:

```
class EmpArea extends MultilingualDataObject {

  public static $db = array(

      'Name' => 'Varchar'
  );


  public function getCMSFields() {

       $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

          $fields->addFieldtoTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Name', 'Employment Area'));
              // add extension updateCMSFields to include translations
      $this->doExtend("updateCMSFields",$fields, get_class());
      return $fields;
  }

}
```

ModelAdmin displays the records perfectly until a filter is applied using the filter widget on the left side of the screen. When you apply a filter ModelAdmin fetches the correct records and filters the gridview but if you click on one of the records to view/edit it it throws a vagrant error:

```
ERROR [User Error]: Couldn't run query: 
SELECT DISTINCT "MultilingualDataObject"."ID"
FROM "MultilingualDataObject"
WHERE ("EmpArea"."Name" LIKE '%HR%') AND ("MultilingualDataObject"."ClassName" IN  'EmpArea'))
LIMIT 30 

Unknown column 'EmpArea.Name' in 'where clause'
IN GET /admin/shared-data/EmpArea/EditForm/field/EmpArea/item/420/edit? q%5BName%5D=HR&action_search=Apply+Filter
Line 580 in /vagrant/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php

Source
======
  571:  }
  572: 
  573:  public function databaseError($msg, $errorLevel = E_USER_ERROR) {
  574:      // try to extract and format query
  575:      if(preg_match('/Couldn\'t run query: ([^\|]*)\|\s*(.*)/', $msg, $matches)) {
  576:          $formatter = new SQLFormatter();
  577:          $msg = "Couldn't run query: \n" . $formatter->formatPlain($matches[1]) .  "\n\n" . $matches[2];
  578:      }
  579: 
* 580:      user_error($msg, $errorLevel);
  581:  }
  582: 
  583:  /**
  584:   * Return a boolean type-formatted string
  585:   *
  586:   * @param array $values Contains a tokenised list of info about this data type
```

This error is thrown on any of the tabs post filtering the gridview and is not restricted to EmpArea.

Any help or suggestions as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is to upgrade SilverStripe to the latest version (currently 3.1.8). It's possible that the problem you have was a bug in the framework code, which may have been fixed since then. That is the first thing I would try.

Comment: I am working in a project with Silverstripe 3.1 and this still does not work. The data is not added to the SiteTree table.

Comment: @MattMan9 did you find the solution?

Comment: @silence sadly no I did not, management decided that the functionality gained wasn't worth the development outlay to fix it so I was re-tasked to other tickets shortly after asking the question.